# PHP function return a variable?

Tags: php, api, function, curl, return

I am having a hard time finding out how to get a function to return a variable that I can use outside of the function, I have tried

```
return $response
```

and I have tried

```
   return $response = $anothervariable
```

But the only way I have been able to get it to work is to echo the response and just put the html in there, I know there is a better way to do this, the problem is I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated!

```
function OpenCNAM($ph) {

$opencnamSID = '*****';
$opencnamTOKEN = '*****';
$query = "https://api.opencnam.com/v2/phone/".$ph."?format=text";
if(isset($opencnamSID)) { $query = "https://".$opencnamSID.":".$opencnamTOKEN."@api.opencnam.com/v2/phone/".$ph."?format=text"; }
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $query);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);   
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);      
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if($response != "") {    
  echo '<span title="'.$response.'"> 888-452-1505</span>';

} else {
    echo 'Nada';
}

}

OpenCNAM('8884521505');
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this? Your first attempt is correct...

Comment: Try var_dump($response)

Answer (score 2):

```
return $response;
```

is correct statement. It will return $response variable if program flow reaches at that point.

You can also pass parameters to function by reference like &$any_variable to set it with the desire value inside the function and play with it outside the function, after the function call.

Answer (score 1):

Remodify your code like this.

```
function OpenCNAM($ph) {

$opencnamSID = '*****';
$opencnamTOKEN = '*****';
$query = "https://api.opencnam.com/v2/phone/".$ph."?format=text";
if(isset($opencnamSID)) { $query = "https://".$opencnamSID.":".$opencnamTOKEN."@api.opencnam.com/v2/phone/".$ph."?format=text"; }
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $query);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);   
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);      
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$str="";
if($response != "") {    
  $str= '<span title="'.$response.'"> 888-452-1505</span>';

} else {
   $str= 'Nada';
}
return $str; //<---------- We are returning here
}

echo OpenCNAM('8884521505'); //<--- If you want to output.. or just $response = OpenCNAM('43535'); if you want to store it in a variable.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just return the texts then you can do like this

```
function OpenCNAM($ph) {
    //...
    //...
    if($response != "") {    
        return '<span title="'.$response.'"> 888-452-1505</span>';

    } else {
        return 'Nada';
    }

}

$foo = OpenCNAM('8884521505');
```

Then, you can do what you want with $foo

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function OpenCNAM($ph)
 {

    $opencnamSID = '*****';
    $opencnamTOKEN = '*****';
    $query = "https://api.opencnam.com/v2/phone/".$ph."?format=text";
    if(isset($opencnamSID)) { $query = "https://".$opencnamSID.":".$opencnamTOKEN."@api.opencnam.com/v2/phone/".$ph."?format=text"; }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $query);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);   
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);      
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if($response != "") 
    {    
        $res =  '<span title="'.$response.'"> 888-452-1505</span>';
    }
    else 
    {
        $res =  'Nada';
    }
return $res;
}

$return_res = OpenCNAM('8884521505');
echo $return_res;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't going to use the returned data anywhere, then echo will do just fine for you.

This was answered in [PHP echo function return value vs echo inside function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602383/php-echo-function-return-value-vs-echo-inside-function)