# Function doesn't return but echo

Tags: php

I am trying to integrate **audiomack** in my website, and I have written a function to make it work.

```
//Get the Audiomack URL
if (!function_exists('samk_audio_audiomack')) {
    function samk_audio_audiomack($url, $width = '100%', $height = 250) {
        if($url!='') {
            $buff = '';
            $buff .= "\n<!-- audiomack | {$plugin_data['name']} | {$plugin_data['url']} -->\n";

            $embed_src = $url;
            $embed_ver_prefix = 'embed4';

            // Check if the embedded source is song or album
            if(stripos($embed_src, '/song/') !== false) { //it is a song
                $embed_src = str_replace('/song/', "/$embed_ver_prefix-large/", $embed_src);
            } else { //it is an album
                $height = 352;
                $embed_src = str_replace('/album/', "/$embed_ver_prefix-album/", $embed_src);
            }

            $height_str = "height='$height'";
            $embed_code = "<iframe src='$embed_src' scrolling='no' width='$width' $height_str scrollbars='no' frameborder='0'></iframe>\n";

            $buff .= "<div class='audiomack_player_container'>\n";
            $buff .= $embed_code;
            $buff .= "</div> <!-- /audiomack_player_container -->\n";

            $buff .= "\n<!-- /audiomack | {$plugin_data['name']} | {$plugin_data['url']} -->\n";

            return $buff;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code I'm using to echo the function:

```
<?php }
if($audiomack_audio!='') {
$audiomack_audio_code = samk_audio_audiomack($audiomack_audio,'100%',250); ?>
<div class="audio-container sermon-tabs" id="audiomack_audio">
<?php echo $audiomack_audio_code; ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

The challenge I am having now is that when I `echo` the function `samk_audio_audiomack($url, $width, $height)`, nothing works. But if I change the `return` to `echo` or `print`, then it returns the value of `$buff`.

Comment: Could you show us the code for the echo as well? And please, indent your code.

Comment: I've added the code for the echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return will "return" the value `$buff` to where the function was called.

If you echo `$buff` inside the function it will echo it out as `PHP` runs through the script else it will give the `$buff` variable data to the variable that called the function.

You can echo from inside your function for flexibility but that would defeat the purpose of the function altogether since a function reduces copy and pasting the same code in loads of different places to echo similar(in your case) ouputs.

See a similar question "[PHP echo function return value vs echo inside function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602383/php-echo-function-return-value-vs-echo-inside-function)"

---

> If called from within a function, the return statement immediately
>   ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as
>   the value of the function call.

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

---

**Examples:**

`$plugin_data['name']` & `$plugin_data['url']` will return undefined since I don't know if its defined else where or not.

```
//$audio_caller now contains what $buff returned
$audio_caller = samk_audio_audiomack('http://www.example.com');

//Use this where you want to echo the function contents
echo $audio_caller;
```

Here is an test of the script below: https://3v4l.org/CuE0f

```
//Get the Audiomack URL
if (!function_exists('samk_audio_audiomack')) {
   function samk_audio_audiomack($url, $width = '100%', $height = 250) {
       if($url!='') {
        $buff = '';
        $buff .= "\n<!-- audiomack | {$plugin_data['name']} | {$plugin_data['url']} -->\n";

        $embed_src = $url;
        $embed_ver_prefix = 'embed4';

        // Check if the embedded source is song or album
        if(stripos($embed_src, '/song/') !== false) { //it is a song
            $embed_src = str_replace('/song/', "/$embed_ver_prefix-large/", $embed_src);
        }else{ //it is an album
            $height = 352;
            $embed_src = str_replace('/album/', "/$embed_ver_prefix-album/", $embed_src);
        }

        $height_str = "height='$height'";
        $embed_code = "<iframe src='$embed_src' scrolling='no' width='$width' $height_str scrollbars='no' frameborder='0'></iframe>\n";

        $buff .= "<div class='audiomack_player_container'>\n";
        $buff .= $embed_code;
        $buff .= "</div> <!-- /audiomack_player_container -->\n";

        $buff .= "\n<!-- /audiomack | {$plugin_data['name']} | {$plugin_data['url']} -->\n";

        return $buff;
       }
    }
}

$audio_caller = samk_audio_audiomack('http://www.example.com');

echo $audio_caller;
```

**EDIT**

On line 1 why is there a close curly brace? `<?php }` //Removed for test

The below example works for me on versions 5.3 to 7.

*Example*: https://3v4l.org/Gss4Q

```
<?php
   $audiomack_audio = 'www.example.com';
   if($audiomack_audio!='') { ?>

        <div class="audio-container sermon-tabs" id="audiomack_audio">

        <?php $audiomack_audio_code = samk_audio_audiomack($audiomack_audio,'100%',250); ?>
        <?php echo $audiomack_audio_code; ?>

        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I've checked through my code, to see if the url and other args are being fetched, but it is still returning a blank page in site.

Comment: @SamuelAsor are the div containers displaying in inspect mode?

Comment: @SamuelAsor then `$audiomack_audio` is not defined, if it was then you would have the first set of dives before the echoing of the function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97272/discussion-between-samuel-asor-and-jamie-sterling).