# Response is not return in API endpoint in Yii Framwork

Tags: php, api, yii2

I have an API in the Yii framework where I'm sending a response but in response not returning data whereas in `echo` & `var_dump()` coming data but not return.

Please give me a solution to what is my mistake in code whereas working with simple echo. Thanks

This is my code

```
    protected function findModel($api_offer_id)
    {   
        $model = Offer::model()->findByAttributes(array("api_offer_id" => $api_offer_id));
        if ($model) {
            return $model;
        } else {
        
            return json_encode(array('status'=>0,'error_code'=>400,'message'=>'Bad request'),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
            exit;
        }
    }

    public function actionUpdate_status($api_offer_id)
    {
        $api_offer_id = $_REQUEST['api_offer_id'];
        $status = $_REQUEST['status'];
        if($api_offer_id) {
            $model = $this->findModel($api_offer_id);

            $model->status = self::offerStatus($status);

            if ($model->save()) {
            
                return json_encode(array('status'=>1,'data'=>array_filter($model->attributes)),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
            
            } else {
                return json_encode(array('status'=>0,'error_code'=>400,'errors'=>$model->errors),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
            }
        }
    }

    public static function offerStatus($status) {
        if($status == "Accepted") {
            return "1";
        }
        if($status == "Rejected") {
            return "2";
        }
    }
```

Comment: look at
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34153065/function-doesnt-return-but-echo) hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

You are missing

```
public function actionUpdate_status($api_offer_id)
{
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    ...
    return [
        'status'=>1,
        'data'=>array_filter($model->attributes)
    ];
```

to tell Yii that this is an `application/json` response. You don't even need the `json_encode()`. See [the docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-response)